# Make a Bilingual SEO depending of user's country

Tags: html, seo, google-search, meta

I've build a website and I'm trying to make a bilingual SEO (french and english), my website has two pages :

mywebsitename.com/ and mywebsitename.com/en (for the english version)

Both has a meta description and title.

The problem is that both link (french and english) appears on the result of the search on google and I would to keep only one of them depend on the user's country:

Example:

If I live in France, I would like that the only link that appear is the french one and if you live in United States or an other english country I would like that the only link that appear is the english one.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide the crawler with more information using the
hreflang attribute to specify different language versions of the page like this

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://mywebsitename.com/de" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://mywebsitename.com/en" />`

Read this.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

You can also consider investing in a ccTLD(country code top-level domain) instead of a generic domain name. (.com, .org etc.). These are webpages ending in country specific two letter identifiers.

```
http://www.mywebsitename.fr
```

where fr stands for France.

ccTLD is the most preferred way to target your audience geographically. Using a ccTLD would would tell the crawler that

```
http://www.mywebsitename.fr

http://www.mywebsitename.us
```

are two different sites altogether. This helps refine the results even better. Anyways. Hope it helps. Thanks for the question.